# EntityFramework - .Select() Projection with anonymous object throws a Exception that I am not sure how to interpret

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

**Exception**

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

This is the call causing this. `Vignette` is a `Collection`, so in my opinion this statement should be valid.

```
public ICollection<CarSharingEntry> GetAllCarSharingEntriesByUserSAM(string userSAM)
{
    try
    {
        using (var _dbContext = new CarSharingContext())
        {
            _dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            return _dbContext.CarSharingEntries
                .Include(e => e.ShareMeeting)
                .Include(e => e.SelectedOptions)
                .Include(e => e.SharedCar)

                 // Code Block causing this v
                .Include(e => e.SharedCar.Vignette
                    .Select(v => new
                    {
                        v.Id,
                        v.GUID,
                        v.CountryName,
                        v.CountryCode
                    })
                )
                // ---------------------------
                .Include(e => e.SharedCar.VehicleType)
                .Include(e => e.SharedCar.Equipment)
                .Include(e => e.SharedCar.FuelType)
                .Include(e => e.SharedCar.Location)
                .Include(e => e.CarSharer.Select(c => c.ContactDetails))
                .Where(e => e.SharedCar.isForCarSharing)
                // Commented out for debugging
                //.Where(e => e.CarSharer.Any(p => p.SAM == userSAM))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include a select with an anonymous type:

```
.Include(e => e.SharedCar.Vignette
    .Select(v => new
    {
        v.Id,
        v.GUID,
        v.CountryName,
        v.CountryCode
    })
)
```

Instead, include the related object directly:

```
.Include(e => e.SharedCar.Select(s => s.Vignette))
```

If you wish to only get some of the values from `Vignette`, you could do this by adding a `.Select(x => new CarSharingEntry { ... })` and specifying what you want to do with each item before the `ToList()`

```
.Select(e => new CarSharingEntry {
    ShareMeeting = e.ShareMeeting,
    SelectedOptions = e.SelectedOptions,
    SharedCar = new SharedCar {
        Vignette = e.SharedCar.Vignette.Select(v => new {
            v.Id,
            v.GUID,
            v.CountryName,
            v.CountryCode
        }),
        VehicleType = e.SharedCar.VehicleType,
        Equipment = e.SharedCar.Equipment,
        // etc, etc...
    },        
}).ToList()
```

Comment: I wish to only get a few selected Properties of Vignette, hence the select(). Could you please create a full code block out out of your assumption? I just want to wrap my head around how to properly perform this by looking at a full, clean example. I would greatly appreciate it if you were so kind.

Comment: ...sigh. I've tried changing bits and pieces around to get this to work but I am getting nowhere. The main problem I seem to have is `CS0266  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<anonymous type: int id, System.Guid GUID, string CountryCode, string CountryName>> can not be implicitly converted to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<CarSharing.DomainClasses.Country>`    when I try to implement your last code block. `.Include(e => e.SharedCar.Select( s => s.Vignette))` isn't even correct code for IntelliSense. I am stumped. Vignettes are nothing else but a virtual ICollection<Country>